# Simple numpy question

Tags: python, numpy

I can't get this snippet to work:

```
#base code

A = array([ [ 1, 2, 10 ],
            [ 1, 3, 20 ],
            [ 1, 4, 30 ],
            [ 2, 1, 15 ],
            [ 2, 3, 25 ],
            [ 2, 4, 35 ],
            [ 3, 1, 17 ],
            [ 3, 2, 27 ],
            [ 3, 4, 37 ],
            [ 4, 1, 13 ],
            [ 4, 2, 23 ],
            [ 4, 3, 33 ] ])

# Number of zones
zones = unique1d(A[:,0])


for origin in zones:
  for destination in zones:
    if origin != destination:
      A_ik = A[(A[:,0] == origin & A[:,1] == destination), 2]
```

Comment: All "this doesn't work" questions should have, at a minimum, (a) the code, (b) the expected results and (c) the actual results - you're missing (b) and (c). Psychic debugging is not yet a well-developed field in IT :-)

Comment: And from a 1k points+ user... I didn't see this one coming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm practicing my Psychic debugging...

Your are missing parentheses in the last line:

```
A_ik = A[(A[:,0] == origin) & (A[:,1] == destination), 2]
```

should work.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing the logical AND operator `&` (which is a bitwise AND) by `&&`?

Comment: (A[:,0]==origin) && (A[:,1]==destination)
                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: The logical and operator in Python is `and`.

Comment: It makes no sense anyway. the return value of (A[:,0]==origin) is an array of booleans. You can't do a logical AND on two arrays.

Comment: NumPy uses '&' as an element-wise operator, which is probably what was intended in this case.